# How to update label from callback function in code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, callback

My ASP.NET project calls a REST-Client library function, which callback should adjust the label. But the asp label won't change or update after callback is called. Is it possible over callback?

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button OnClick="connect" Text="Connect" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label to be changed" id="Label1">
        </asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
public void connect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program restCLient = new Program();
    restCLient.startConnection(writeToConsole);
}

public void writeToConsole(string str)
{
    Label1.Text = str;
}
```

**Programm.cs:**

```
public void startConnection(Action<string> callbackLog)
{
    callbackLog("result");
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug if writeToConsole was called?

Comment: your writeToConsole function should be in Program.cs i guess,

Comment: But i cannot access the Label1 from outside the code behind

Comment: dont use callback just return a value in ur startConnection function and used it to check in your default page so you have access on the label.

Comment: But i need to receive many strings jit during a loading process

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label1 is not referenced in startConnection, it will have a new instance. Best way to do this is to return a string from startConnection and change the label in connect() method.

One workaround is to send the calling page instance as a parameter to the startConnection method and call the method on that parameter. Assuming your page class is called Default and Programm.cs is in the same application you can use something like this:

```
public void startConnection(ref Default callingPage)
{
    callingPage.writeToConsole("result");
}
```

Then you would call the method like this:

```
restCLient.startConnection(this);
```

Comment: In Debug it shows me, that Label1 is referenced. But maybe the page won't update?! A return string is no option, since i need to return many of them during a loading process.

Comment: When writeToConsole is called from startConnection, it creates a new instance of Default.aspx.cs and calls the method, so all changes to it's controls will not reflect on the actual calling page, try to debug the Label1 value and see if the value is updated after restCLient.startConnection(writeToConsole); is executed.
You can also return a List<> of values from that method.

Comment: Okay, case closed. I tested again and the label which is getting changed is depending on the new instance of default.aspx. Thanks for this hint! So i can't use a callback function here. Do you know a work around for this? I try to avoid modifying my library project including program.cs as much as i can...

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a sample code, see if that works in your project.

Comment: My intention was to seperate the webapplication and the library (program.cs). So it won't work for me. Maybe the workaround will help some other.